# Json usng jsp and servlets

Tags: java, jquery, json, charts

I need a help regarding I am using longdata inside JSON object.

I am new to JSON and jQuery.

I am using Servlet, jsp, JSON, jQuery.

I want to retrieve JSON object values from servlet using jQuery in jsp. Display those values into line chart or bar chart.

JSON object looks like this:

```
{ "pageHits": [30, 60, 22, 5, 60, 88, 102], "rssHits": [33, 45, 121, 23, 55, 35, 77], "xAxis": ['Jan 2009', 'Feb 2009', 'Mar 2009', 'Apr 2009', 'May 2009', 'June 2009', 'Jul 2009'] }
```

please send me the sample one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HighChart](http://www.highcharts.com/) for the charting purpose, it does use Json data.
Kindly go through documentation and [examples](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/), they're good enough.

As far as sending data from servlet is concerned all you need to do is use something like this for your controler,

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/demoLink.htm" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    Map<String, Object> sendData(@RequestParam(value = "locationId", required = false) Integer locationId) {

/** Calculate Values **/
/** Put them in HashMap (or something like that) **/
return map;
}
```

It will automatically serialize and send as json to jquery.

If you need further help let me know.!!!

Comment: my question is json object get the values from running server and display the values in chart.this is my requirement.so i can use servlet,jsp,json,jquery and charts.so can you please help me

Comment: I am seriously confused about what exactly you wanted to say above..!!

Comment: my server is Zenoss.using json api to get the values from zenoss dashboard and display those values in to chart.this is my requirment.so i can use servlet,jsp,json,jquery to display the chart

Comment: i need using json data,jquery to display the line chart.please help me

Comment: please can you give me any link or example